# Can anyone identify the orthogonal polynomial for this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I have come across this recurrence relation:
\begin{equation}
x p_n(x) = (N - n)(n + 1) p_{n+1}(x) + (N - n + 1) n p_{n - 1}(x)
\end{equation}
with $p_{-1}(x) = p_{N + 1}(x) = 0$.  I expect $p_n(x)$ to be an orthogonal polynomial.  Initially, I guessed a Kravchuk polynomial, but this doesn't seem to work.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Suppose that the polynomials in question exist. Let us write $p_n(x)=a_n x^{n}+\ldots$ and try to make them monic by finding $a_n$. These coefficients satisfy
$$a_n=(N-n)(n+1)a_{n+1},$$
therefore we may set $a_n=\frac{(N-n)!}{n!}$. Now define monic polynomials $q_n(x):=\frac{p_n(x)}{a_n}$. They will satisfy
$$xq_n(x)=q_{n+1}(x)+n^2\left(N-n+1\right)^2q_{n-1}(x).$$
This implies that the weight should be an even function of $x$.

Comment: The coefficient $n^2(N-n+1)^2$ can be identified with dual Hahn polynomials where $\gamma = \delta = 0$, e.g. http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/askey/ch1/par6/par6.html. However I could not identify (in my head) the middle part with $0$, so I'm not sure if they are dual Hahn polynomials.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  The problem is symmetric if you replace $n$ with $N - n + 1$; is this related to the result that the weight should be even in $x$?  Also, I have two general questions:  (1) Is it true that if $p_n(x)$ obeys a recurrence relation of the form for an orthogonal polynomial then it must be some linear combination of known orthogonal polynomials?  (2) Can one find the roots of $p_n(x)$ from its recurrence relation without finding the full form?  I don't know much about this area of mathematics.